# Find sum of unique parameter in list - linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of lines, the lines contains list of calls (call has DestinationNumber property)

here's my line model

```
 public class Line
{
    public Line()
    {
        Calls = new List<Call>();
        Messages = new List<Sms>();
        Payments = new List<Payment>();
    }
    public int LineId { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public Package Package { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Call> Calls { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Sms> Messages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }

    public string LineNumber { get; set; }
    public LineStatus Status { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? RemovedDate { get; set; }
}
```

and here's my call model

```
 public class Call
{
    public int CallId { get; set; }

    public int LineId { get; set; }
    public Line Line { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfCall { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string DestinationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I  want to Count() the number of unique calls

I tried something like that..

```
Lines.Sum(line=>line.Calls.Sum(call=>call.DestinationNumber.Where(/*if DestiantionNumber not counted before*/))
```

Comment: What you mean _"by count of DestinationNumber "_?

Comment: uh, how to know *if DestiantionNumber not counted before*? could you post the model of `Calls`?

Comment: @BagusTesa DestiantionNumber is simple string I just need to sum how meny unique people This line call

Comment: You should read [ask] and then provide us with a [mcve]. That would include a full class model, sample data, and your expected output.

Comment: @ישראלקוסייב - The answer you've selected doesn't seem to meet the requirement of "I want to Count() the number of unique calls". BFree's answer seems more like what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
var count = lines.SelectedMany(l => l.Calls)
     .Select(c => c.DestinationNumber)
     .Distinct()
     .Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

`GroupBy` approach this picks all calls by their `DestinationNumber` which exist only once `x.Count() == 1` and counts them `Count()`

```
int result = line.Calls.GroupBy(x => x.DestinationNumber).Count(x => x.Count() == 1);
```